# Concatenate the System Environment Variable in Azure pipeline CmdLine@2 script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to run the pencover.console in the azure pipeline yml batch script and the path to the console is kept in the system environment variable. I've tried various way to but still unable to run the console. The error i get "While parsing a quoted scalar, find unknown escape character." and below is my code. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Test solution
    inputs: 
      script:
        "%OPENCOVER%\opencover.console.exe" "-target:vstest.console.exe" "-targetargs:\"$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\**\*Tests.dll\"" "-output:$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults\$(Build.Repository.Name).coverage.xml" "-excludebyfile:**/Migrations/*;**moq*;**FluentAssertions*" "-excludebyattribute:*.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage;*.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute;*.ExcludeFromCoverage;*.ExcludeFromCoverageAttribute;*.GeneratedCode;*.GeneratedCodeAttribute" -register:path64 -mergebyhash -hideskipped:all
```

To run the pipeline task successfully

Answer (score 0):

You may try to print your call to see what exactly cmd runs...:

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Print cmd
    inputs: 
      script:
        echo "%OPENCOVER%\opencover.console.exe" "-target:vstest.console.exe" ...
```

At first view, you may update your `targetargs` to `"-targetargs:$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\**\*Tests.dll"` because it should not contain spaces..

Answer (score 0):

Testing on my side using your yaml, I can reproduce the issue. To solve this error, add single quotes to the entire script as shown below.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Test solution
    inputs: 
      script:
        '"%OPENCOVER%\opencover.console.exe" "-target:vstest.console.exe" "-targetargs:\"$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\**\*Tests.dll\"" "-output:$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults\$(Build.Repository.Name).coverage.xml" "-excludebyfile:**/Migrations/*;**moq*;**FluentAssertions*" "-excludebyattribute:*.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage;*.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute;*.ExcludeFromCoverage;*.ExcludeFromCoverageAttribute;*.GeneratedCode;*.GeneratedCodeAttribute" -register:path64 -mergebyhash -hideskipped:all'
```

[image]